# Socket io CORS error Can't Connect Client To Nodejs Server Through Socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I have working Nodejs server which I reach at localhost:4000 (working fine). I'm trying to connect a client through socketio to server outside of Nodejs. From localhost:8888/page (MAMP app) to a socket, but I'm getting `ERR_FAILED 200` in console. There's something preventing from connecting to a socket.

Nodejs server.js:

```
import fetch from 'node-fetch';
import express from 'express';
const app = express();
import http from 'http';
const server = http.createServer(app);
import {Server} from 'socket.io';
const io = new Server(server);
import mysql from 'mysql';

{...}

server.listen('4000', () => {
  console.log("Server running on port 4000");
});
```

a webpage outside of node app:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title></title>
  <script src="https://cdn.socket.io/4.4.1/socket.io.min.js" integrity="sha384-fKnu0iswBIqkjxrhQCTZ7qlLHOFEgNkRmK2vaO/LbTZSXdJfAu6ewRBdwHPhBo/H" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </script>
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<script src="http://localhost:4000/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>

const socket = io.connect('http://localhost:4000/');


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Please help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://socket.io/docs/v3/handling-cors/

```
const io = require("socket.io")(httpServer, {
  cors: {
    origin: "https://example.com",
    methods: ["GET", "POST"]
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, also found this solution in socket.io docs